# Changing an abstract variable

Tags: java

Alright so I have an abstract class. Like the following.

```
public abstract class GameObject {  
// VARIABLES //
protected float x = 0;
protected float y = 0;
}
```

*I actually have more to it than this but this is all that is needed.

What I am wanting to do is change x and y for all the classes extended off GameObject.
So if I did something like

```
x += 1;
y += 1;
```

Then every class that extends GameObject has the variables x and y = 1.

How would I go about doing  this?

Comment: every class or every Object? You could edit your previous post rather to create a new one.

Comment: These are instance variables, they cannot be set by class.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that as they currently are. They are *instance* variables, meaning that each instance of `GameObject` gets its own copy of the variables. If they are static variables, then all instances would share them.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use two new variables in the class that renders the game, e.g. `viewX` and `viewY`, which you add to an object's x and y before drawing it. By modifying these two variables you can shift around all objects without modifying much data, e.g. like this:

```
float viewX = 0, viewY = 0;

void render() {
    for (GameObject o : gameObjects)
        draw(o.image, o.x + viewX, o.y + viewY);
}

void setCamera(float x, float y) {
    viewX = x;
    viewY = y;
}
```